# Remmina Startup Program

Tags: command-line, startup, remmina

I am looking to set remmina (more specifically a remmina file) to boot when the Ubuntu 14.04 system boots. I was looking for help as to what command to enter for a certain .remmina file to boot. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean a remmina  config file to be established at boot time? Because Remmina is a GUI-interfaced app and will not wake up before some GUI session be opened.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Do you know how long the wait command needs to be and how to write in the wait?

Comment: you can put `sleep 100s ; <remina command>` needs the semi colon - that is 'then'  - how long it needs to be is up to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have connected to the remote system before, there will be a config file for this connection in `~/.remmina/`.  The config file will be of the form `[numeric string].remmina`.  If you have several files, I know of no easy way to find the one you want from looking at the file names.  However, you can open the files with a text editor until you find the one you want.

Once you know which config file to use `[desired-config-file].remmina`, the terminal command line to start remmina in that config file is `remmina -c [desired-config-file].remmina`.

You can simply add this command line to Startup Applications in Ubuntu.

As a commenter said, you don't want this command line to execute until your desktop has started.  You may have to add a wait command to achieve that; unfortunately I don't remember how to do that.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04, the config files are in ~/.local/share/remmina