# Remote connection to server

Tags: server, remote-desktop

so what i am looking to do is have one ubuntu server then using xrdp connect multiple users to that one server with there own desktop. I have got it so i can connect via my ubuntu PC via RDP to the server but what i really need is the person to load there PC then it boots up with a login box, they login and that logins them into the server, so no desktop GUI on there PC just a simple login if this makes sense. I have searched high and low but cannot find anything to help me achieve this :(

Comment: you want a GUI login but no GUI desktop? Or do you want a text-only way of connecting to the server? or something else? This question is very unclear.

Comment: or do you want the clients to have no desktop on their own devices and rely solely on the server desktop? a thin client?

Comment: Sorry for not wording this well, ive been trying to get my head around it. I need something like this https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/09/ubuntu-12-10-login-screen-adds-remote-desktop-access

I know this is a old version but the idea is you login via the login screen but that remotes into the external server rather then the desktop on the computer but i cant seem to find any news on how to do it with the latest ubuntu

Comment: looks like there is an answer here: [Connect to login screen over VNC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033274/ubuntu-18-04-connect-to-login-screen-over-vnc), and it involves switching back to lightdm as a greeter, which is capable of doing this. For latest Ubuntu you will also need to first switch to Xorg instead of Wayland (since Wayland is now default, and this solution works with x11vnc)

Comment: No i have seen that but it dosent look like its what i need

Comment: why isn't it what you need? That is exactly what the omgubuntu article you linked does. The difference is that it uses VNC instead of RDP. You might be able to get RDP working that way, but I don't know how and haven't seen anything.

Comment: All it did was give me a diffrent looking login but no option to add a server

Comment: oh my I actually just understood what's actually happening there, sorry. No, that is not what you're looking for. It appears that the service was one offered by Canonical (and no longer offered)

Comment: You can probably put together a hacky solution where you auto-login to a GUI and then set an RDP client to autostart with the correct connection as is done [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947138/remmina-startup-program) but a) I don't know enough to give complete instructions and b) the user would still have access to a "local" Linux install, which may or may not be desired.

Answer (score 0):

Solved so first login set your self to auto login and load up your server with remmina next quoteing

"
[Remmina Startup Program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/947138/remmina-startup-program)
Organic Marble

Assuming you have connected to the remote system before, there will be a config file for this connection in ~/.remmina/. The config file will be of the form [numeric string].remmina. If you have several files, I know of no easy way to find the one you want from looking at the file names. However, you can open the files with a text editor until you find the one you want.

Once you know which config file to use [desired-config-file].remmina, the terminal command line to start remmina in that config file is remmina -c [desired-config-file].remmina.

You can simply add this command line to Startup Applications in Ubuntu.

As a commenter said, you don't want this command line to execute until your desktop has started. You may have to add a wait command to achieve that; unfortunately I don't remember how to do that.
"

Once you have done that download remmina-plugin-kiosk
https://installati.one/ubuntu/22.04/remmina-plugin-kiosk/

When logging in change your GUI to remmina kiosk and bam it now take you to your server login every time :D